# why emulator not open in API level 19

Tags: android, android-emulator

Why my android emulator not open in API level 19. i installed system image also, but it open in API level 16. Actually what criteria we use that emulator open in API level 19. please let me know how can i do that...

Comment: update your sdk tools

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to have an AVD defined for API 19. Second, if a compatible AVD is not already running and a compatible device is not attached to the system, the launch configuration will default to the lowest API level that is compatible with your app (as determined by what you set in the manifest). You can override this by opening the run configurations (Run > Run Configurations...), selecting the "Target" tab, and selecting a preferred AVD.